# Tranformed date to next month if date falling on 29,30 and 31

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table with a date field with datatype INT look like this

```
Date
20140430
20140514
20140508
```

the format is `YYYYMMDD`
now i need to transform the date format to `YYYY-MM-DD`
with whatever DD = 29,30 and 31 it will automatically move the first day ofthe next month
so for example

```
case when date = 20140430 then '2014-05-01'
```

Comment: The subtraction 2014-05-01 = 2008.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: sorry the datatye is INT

Comment: And how do you plan to add the new format in int datatype ? Do you want to move it to some other table ?

Comment: Don't mess around with integer or char, use proper date/time data types.

Comment: This needs repeating, over and over and over. Use the correct type. In this case, `date`. Using integer or text types is a **very serious bug** that simply can't be covered up by casting and conversions. A `date` is just **3 bytes**, smaller than `int`'s **4 bytes**. You gain nothing at all by using an `int` column to store dates

Comment: BTW dates have no format, they are binary types. Formats apply only when parsing strings (date literals) into dates or generating strings from dates. If you use a date type you won't have to worry about formats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `DAY()` to get the day of the month and then use `EOMONTH` to get the last date of the month. Add 1 day to it to get first of next month

```
CASE WHEN DAY(DateCol) in (29, 30, 31) 
     THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DateCol)) 
     ELSE DateCol
     END
```

Answer (score 1):

As you described it, you can solve it by using a simple CASE... However, maybe you want to switch only the last day of the month to the first day of the next month? In this case you can modify the case a little to evaluate the DATEDIFF between your date and the first day of the next month. Anyways, following an example for the case I mentioned:

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT 20140430 AS d
UNION ALL
SELECT 20140514
UNION ALL
SELECT 20140508
),
cteDate AS(
SELECT CAST(CAST(d AS NVARCHAR(8)) AS DATE)  AS MyDate
  FROM cte
)
SELECT *, CASE WHEN DATEPART(d, MyDate) IN (29, 30, 31) THEN DATEADD(d, -1 * ( DATEPART(d, MyDate) - 1), DATEADD(MONTH, 1, MyDate)) ELSE MyDate END AS MyNewDate
  FROM cteDate
```

Comment: Using `int` instead of `date` is a very serious bug that needs to be fixed first, not covered up

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's quite common to store the date in this format - faced it may times in various projects I worked in. Guess it's more performant if it comes to indexing etc. Anyways, the OP didn't write if the table with the int column was created by him or if it was given to him "as it is" and he has to import the data from there.

Comment: No it's not. Quite the opposite, precisely because it's **far worse** in performance, storage (`date` is just 3 bytes), language support and vulnerable to localization issues. That's what makes this such a serious bug. You may find such workarounds for databases that *don't* have date types like SQLite, but nor SQL Server.

Comment: You may find such workarounds in very old SQL Server databases (SQL Server 2005 or older), when `date` wasn't available. There's no need for this since 2008 though. Even in 2005, using `int` instead of `datetime` meant date correlation optimizations couldn't be used.

Comment: guilty - been mostly projects ehich dated back may years... and according to the formula "never change a running system" it has never been changed... just currently working at a project where we got hundreds of tables with this kind of date storage. Fortunately the format YYYYMMDD can natively be translated by SQL Server to date without the hassle of localization etc. (at least we didn't expereience any problems so far). Would be worse with the german format DDMMYYYY....

Comment: That's not a German format. Every country except the US puts the day before the month. The German and Russian formats use dots as separators. "Translating" or applying any kind of function on a field in general, prevents the server from using any indexes covering the field. The only exception are ... date fields where `cast(field as date)=@someDate` is treated as `field >=@someDate and field <dateadd(d,1,@someDate)`. This leads to bad statistics estimates but it's still better than the full table scan caused by casting

Comment: Therefore indexing on the int field... in the (BI) projects I work the tables are joined to a date table, therefore we don't have a cast to date during the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE  #CAL ([Date] INT)
    INSERT INTO #CAL VALUES
    (20140430),
    (20140514),
    (20140508)
    GO
    
SELECT
 [Date] ,
 CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date], 101), -- convert to date
 CASE when day(CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date], 101))> 28 
    THEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date], 101))+1, 0)
    ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date], 101) END
    FROM #CAL
    
    DROP TABLE #CAL
```

Output

```
Date    (No column name)    (No column name)
20140430    20140430    2014-05-01 00:00:00.000
20140514    20140514    2014-05-14 00:00:00.000
20140508    20140508    2014-05-08 00:00:00.000
```